# java widening final variable

Tags: java, primitive, operation

I'm reading java OCA certification documentation. 
Some primitive operations  behavior seems realy strange for me.

it is said that all `byte`, `short` and `char` value are automatically    widening to `int` when used as operand for arithmetic operations. this is perfectily logic. but confusion come when  we make this operands final.

this code will not compile (logic)

```
 short s1 = 10 ;
 short s2 = 20 ;
 short sum = s1 + s2;
```

but this one will compile

```
  final short s1 = 10 ;
  final short s2 = 20 ;
  short sum = s1 + s2;
```

Why this will compil successfuly? what property of the keyword `final` make this code compile?

Comment: *what property of the keyword final make this code compile?* **Nothing**. You are reaching a ***compiler*** optimization caused [constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It makes s1 and s2 compile-time constant expressions, so the addition is done by the compiler, not at runtime, and the code is thus equivalent to

```
short sum = 30;
```

The compiler is thus able to know that the value assigned to `sum` is small enough to fit into a short, and it thus compiles.

Comment: done dear JB Niezet. 

But i was thinking the precision about  data range was usefull. Nethermind i delete the anwser

Comment: *The compiler is thus able to know that the value assigned to sum is small enough to fit into a short*.